# Facebook JSON object in file_get_contents("php://input") doesn't return value

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to print out the or access the JSON objects returned by the POST request from Facebook. Here's the code:

```
<?php

define('VERIFY_TOKEN', 'mysecretverifytokenstring');                                    
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];                             

if ($method == 'GET' && $_GET['hub_mode'] == 'subscribe' && $_GET['hub_verify_token'] == VERIFY_TOKEN) {
   echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
} else if ($method == 'POST') {

        $post_body = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $object = json_decode($post_body, true);

    print_r($object);
}

?>
```

This would not output any, even though I can connect in Realtime Updates successfully.

Comment: did you try echoing out $post_body directly?

Comment: What does `$post_body` contain?

Comment: I can't really see its value since this php file is only called by the Facebook Realtime Update, so even I apply echo or print_r, it wouldn't display in the browser.

Comment: what does "php://input" refer to in file_get_contents("php://input") ?

Comment: It should contain raw data from the request body. You may read here: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php